# How to get values of un-ordered html list in jquery through (.each loop)?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get index values for unordered list through each loop in jquery, i am struggling to get that.
I need the soltion with jquery each loop only, please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>``
<head>
<title></title>

<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('li').each(function(index){
     //do stuff
     console.log(index);
    });
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>

     <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
     </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What output your code produces and how it is different from what you expect?

Comment: i am getting output as dotted list i.e, unordered list, but i need index value insted of dot for each element like. 0 Link 1, 1 Link 2, 2 Link 3 , like this.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: why don't you use ordered list`<ol>` instead of unordered`<ul>`? ordered list will give you the required result.

Comment: it's easy to use ordered list but i want the solution through jquery as i am learning jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one, I hope it will help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('li a').each(function(index){
     $(this).text(index + " " + $(this).text());
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks, it is working fine.

Comment: glad to know that it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

`this` should do it and append new elements to the page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('li a').each(function(index){
 console.log(index, $(this).text());
 $(['<h1>',index," ",$(this).text(),'</h1>'].join('')).appendTo('body');
});
});
```

Comment: thanks, can you help with what should i write instead of console.log to display it on webpage, the result is only showing in the console.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to create and display another list on your page? See my edit.